# Why does using dblQuotedString change the match location?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have the following python program:

```
from pyparsing import *

#grammar START
string_list_item = dblQuotedString | Word(printables.replace(')', ''))
cmake_list_content = OneOrMore(string_list_item)

variable_name = Word(alphas+"_", alphanums+"_")

set_keyword = CaselessLiteral("set")

set_normal_variable_stmt = set_keyword + "(" \
    + variable_name \
        + cmake_list_content + ")" 
#grammar END

cmake_source = "set(TabsPls_Sources Main.cpp)"

string_list_item.setDebug()

set_normal_variable_stmt.parseString(cmake_source)
```

This gives the following output for 'Main.cpp':

```
Match {string enclosed in double quotes | W:(0123...)} at loc 19(1,20)
Matched {string enclosed in double quotes | W:(0123...)} -> ['Main.cpp']
```

But when I remove the dblQuotedString from the first line:

```
Match W:(0123...) at loc 20(1,21)
Matched W:(0123...) -> ['Main.cpp']
```

Why does that happen? There aren't any double quoted strings in the input so why does the match location change?

Comment: This issue was addressed in Issue #244 in the pyparsing github repo: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/issues/244

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the underlying problem was a library bug, which was addressed externally as a library issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question myself because this was due to a [bug #244](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/issues/244), which has now been fixed!